# What is the geometric relationship between $A$ and $A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Posed a more specific way:

Let $A \in \mathbb R ^ {m \times n}$ and $S_k$ be the unit $k$-sphere.

What is the exact geometric relationship between $E_m = \{ A\vec x \mid \vec x \in S_m \}$ and $E_n = \{ A^T\vec y \mid \vec y \in S_n \}$?

Comment: What makes you think there is such a relationship?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It would be a shame if there wasn't one. I'm interested in "is there?" and "what is it".

Comment: I would try it for some very small values of $m$ and $n$ and some simple matrix $A$ and see whether there is anything to be seen.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For full rank $2 \times 2$ matrices, both ellipsoids have the same volume (same determinant). For unitary matrices, the transpose is the inverse, but it also ends up transforming unit circles to unit circles. For $2 \times 2$, the most easily observable dimension, nothing interesting happens in general. Past $\dim(A) \le 3$, it becomes difficult to observe the geometry of resulting ellipsoids (the lack of a comprehensible 4+-dimensional visualization). If there were mathematicians with a better understanding geometry than I, I was hoping they could add input where I lack insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $m>n$ define  the SVD as

$$A=U[\Sigma\;0]V^T$$

Since the sphere is unaffected by rotations,

$$E_m =\{U [\Sigma\;0] \vec{x} \mid \vec{x} \in S_m\}= \{U \Sigma \vec{x} \mid \vec{x} \in B_n\} $$

where $B_n$ is the $n$-ball. Therefore $E_m$ is the $n$-ball  scaled by $\Sigma$ and rotated by $U$. For $A^T$

$$E_n =\left\{V \left[{\Sigma \atop 0}\right] \vec{x} \mid \vec{x} \in S_n\right\}$$

we have a scaling of the $n$ sphere by $\Sigma$ then rotated into $m$-dimensional space by $V$.

If we ignore rotation/embedding in space, both objects have the same bounding shape, but $E_m$ is filled while $E_n$ is not.